# Python rcParams error

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have installed both Anaconda and MacPorts to install various python packages and receive the following error when I try to import matplotlib:

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import conda
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 169, in <module>
    from urllib2 import urlopen
  File "/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 104, in <module>
    import bisect
  File "bisect.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams
ImportError: cannot import name rcParams
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks as though you've got a module of your own called `bisect.py`; that's shadowing the standard library's `bisect` module.  Rename your `bisect.py` module and retry.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now I receive a new error though.                ImportError: dlopen(/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2): Library not loaded: libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/ft2font.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: That's a completely different issue, and probably one for the conda folks: the solution will depend on how you're installing matplotlib and its dependencies (like freetype).

Comment: Are you installing matplotlib with conda?

Comment: @MarkDickinson - fancy putting your comment in as a question so OP can tick it and the question can be closed.

Comment: @ajostergaard: Done.  Thanks!

Comment: @ajostergaard: Well, looks like no-one cares. Answer deleted.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink. :)

Comment: @MarkDickinson, I just had this problem and your (deleted) answer was incredibly useful.  I've voted to undelete and will up-vote if you undelete ...

Comment: @BenBolker: Done. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by a file `bisect.py` in your current directory, which shadows the [`bisect` module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html): when you import matplotlib, matplotlib imports the `urllib2` library, which in turn tries to import the *standard library* `bisect` module.  Unfortunately, because of the way that Python's import name resolution works, `urllib2` ends up importing your *local* `bisect.py` instead of the standard library one.

Note that at this point (the point where your `bisect.py` starts to be imported) we're still only halfway though the matplotlib import, since the matplotlib import can't be completed until it's finished importing `urllib2`, which in turn can't be completed until the `bisect.py` import is complete.  That means that only some of the objects that the matplotlib import defines have been defined.

Now your `bisect.py` script apparently tries to make some more imports from matplotlib, and because the matplotlib namespace hasn't been fully populated yet you end with an `ImportError`.

Possible solutions: (1) rename your `bisect.py` script to something else;  (2) start the Python interpreter from a different directory (one that doesn't contain your `bisect.py` script).

In general, the recommendation is to avoid giving your own modules or top-level packages names that match something in the standard library. Rather than having to have encyclopaedic knowledge of what's in the standard library, the easiest way to achieve this is to avoid names that are too generic.  `numbers.py`, `math.py` and `random.py` are probably the most common offenders.

For diagnosing this sort of error in the future, note the line:

```
File "bisect.py", line 2, in <module>
```

in the traceback: all other lines show a module within `/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7`, so are coming from the standard library or from a third-party package (like matplotlib) installed in `/Users/colinross/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages`; the lack of path shows that `bisect.py` is being imported from the current directory.